# What has happened to Google Chrome Developer Console? Error detail is miminized

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

What has happened to Google Chrome Developer Console?

My error messages are being minimized so that I can't see them.  All I get is a pink line.
[image]

I have tried resetting to the default settings.

[image]

[image]

Once I do this the console is back to normal.
[image]

**But as soon as I refresh browser page, it's back to the single pink line.**

I've tried fiddling around with the filters but this doesn't work either.  Also the little filter button is gone now.

Here is my before and after settings once I click the reset button.  No difference here that I can tell.

[image]

[image]

Here is my browser version.
[image]

Has anyone else had this happen? It's driving me crazy resetting between every refresh...

Comment: Looks like a bug. See if it's fixed in Chrome Canary, otherwise consider reporting on https://crbug.com

Comment: I have this issue too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Google fixed this with a browser update.  It doesn't behave like before.
[image]